# How to organize Mongo collections in this case?

Tags: mongodb

I am reading on MongoDB and still cannot understand in what cases should I prefer document-oriented DBs over traditional ones like Postgres.

Consider the following: I have a blog, which consists of posts, and users can write comments on posts. So I create two collections: `users` and `posts`. Each `post` contains an array of embedded documents - `comments`, so that each time I load a `post` from DB, I automatically get all `comments`. This is fine and in fact Mongo seems to be a better choice if I know *for sure* that relations won't change. But everything does.

### 1. Breaking relations.

Suppose I will decide to show user's comments on his/her profile page. I will have to create an index on `posts.comments.user_id` and select from `posts` by `user._id`. So this is basically the same thing I do in RDBMS. Or I'll have to copy all `comments` from `posts` to `users` and *manually* make sure these two sets stay synched in the future (no triggers & no transactions in Mongo).

### 2. Adding a field

Now I add a new field to posts, like `rating` and for those records that already exist I want to set `rating = number of comments`. But I can't do this kind of mass-update. Either I set *the same value for all updated documents* (`{ $set: {rating: 1} }`) or I have to manually loop one-by-one.

### 3. Making reports

How do I find most active users? Because there are no `joins` - first, I will have to extract top `posts.comments.user_id` and keep them somewhere. Then go one `_id` at a time and select `user.name`. This can be solved in by keeping `user.name` in `comment`. But what if later I will need more fields?

### What is my question?

Have I got something wrong? These three cases seem to be simple extensions for a blog application. If I am not 100% sure from the beginning about the structure of relations and statistics, and ... (which in 99% real cases) I shouldn't be using Mongo?

Comment: those are good questions, but before making a decision for a non-SQL DB like MongoDB, I would recommend to first look at the problem domain, and check if you need primarily relations and joins, or if you primarily need to access records which contain "mixed" data. e.g. what is your expected access pattern?  If you always access one type of records, and it is beneficial to have all associated data embedded instead of accessing it through relations, and the related information does not need to be updated through different "paths", then MongoDB is a great candidate for a no-SQL DB.

Comment: @Tilo, I am actually asking this for understanding, not that I have some problem right now before me. I just read about NoSQL and cannot figure out in what real problem (e.g. something may change in future) I would wish to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting and instructive questions.

1. Changes in requirements mean changes in the software.  Moving the comments from the posts to the user would definitely be a pretty drastic change, but I would still argue that with MongoDB a change like that can be less painful than with RDBMS.  For example, the application could be modified so it can deal with *both* variants at the same time: comments in posts and comments in users.  This way, the data could be migrated to the new structure over time rather than all at once. -- Keeping comments *both* in the user and in the post seems a rather bad decision to me though.  If the data changes often, that is a strong argument *not* to denormalize it.
2. The update you describe is trivial to implement in any programming language or in MongoDB's native javascript shell.  The fact that the query language itself doesn't allow that kind of complex update does not mean that it cannot be done easily with MongoDB.  I would argue that the query language being more stream-lined than full-blown SQL is actually a good thing.
3. Careful denormalizing (by putting user.name into the comment itself) can indeed help here. Since user.name would rarely change, that is a much better case for that kind of denormalization than putting the comments into both users and posts.  Once again, the flexibility of MongoDB begins to shine if you do this selectively, dynamically — you can put the user.name into a comment when you get to it, but the application can be written so it can handle both cases: if the user.name is not in the comment it is looked up (and then maybe written to the comment to save future lookups).  You can "cache" more attributes in the comment as you go.

In general, MongoDB leads to a more flexible, agile way of thinking about data structures and implementing them in the database.  Many programmers find that more intuitive and easier to work with than SQL's rigidity.  But there is no technology that has only advantages, and you can always find problems where one approach leads to a better, more elegant solution than the other.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Keeping fields that are rarely changed in both collections can indeed help. So, before using NoSQL I must realize quite well the structure and relations. However, lack of transactions and joins still bugs me, e.g. in 2) - this becomes complicated as number of collections increases because I have to store all `_id`s and their interconnections. And in high-load app how can I be sure that values don't change while my script is running?

Answer (score 0):

You simply solve your problem through your programming language. It's instinct to modify your SQL query to vary your results, but you'd simply use your javascript to pull the new piece of data in.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but why would I want to use instead of RDBMS where at least I have transactions... E.g. to make two records in synch with each other I have to do two separate requests from my code to DB, and there is no guarantee that they will *both* end successfully. What should I do if the first is ok and second fails?